# Ошибка при работе с CORS policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

Код post-запроса такой:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {Router} = require('express');
const router = Router();


let jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

router.post('/', jsonParser,(req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json('Hi')
});

module.exports = router;
```

Прочел уже информацию во многих источниках о предзапросах к стороннему домену, однако получаю все равно ошибку: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Устанока `mode: 'no-cors'` конечно, проблему решает, но хотел обойтись без этого. В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Что у вас в req.headers.origin?

Comment: Там локалхост с портом проекта клиентского приложения

Comment: http://localhost:8080

Comment: Preflight запрос делается методом OPTIONS и именно на него надо ответить этими заголовками. У вас вообще нет обработки таких запросов

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо большое за совет. Надо будет попробовать.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

function processCors(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  next();
}

app.use(processCors);
app.listen(...);
```